# Copy billing address to shipping address using javascript

Tags: javascript, function

Im trying to get my page to use the same as billing address checkbox to copy the information to the shipping address but it is not working. 
Here is my HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=page-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Snoot Flowers - Order</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="snoot.css" />
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <script src="modernizr.custom.65897.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="container">
      <header>
         <h1>
            Snoot Flowers
         </h1>
      </header>

      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Floral Arrangements</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Seasonal Bouquets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Live Plants</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shop by Price</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </div>

   <article>
      <h2>Place an Order</h2>
      <div id="errorText"></div>
      <form action="results.htm">
         <fieldset id="message" class="checks">
            <legend>Message</legend>
            <input id="congrats" name="Congratulations" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="congrats">Congratulations!</label>
            <input id="bday" name="HappyBirthday" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="bday">Happy Birthday!</label>
            <input id="anniv" name="HappyAnniversary" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="anniv">Happy Anniversary!</label>
            <input id="love" name="ILoveYou" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="love">I love you!</label>
            <input id="custom" name="CustomMessage" type="checkbox" />
            <label for="custom">Custom message:</label>
            <textarea id="customText" name="CustomText" placeholder="Enter custom message here (max 250 characters)"></textarea>
            <div class="errorMessage"></div>
          </fieldset>
         <fieldset id="billingAddress" class="text">
            <legend>Billing Address</legend>
            <label for="billFName">First Name</label>
            <input id="billFName" name="BillingFirstName" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="billLName">Last Name</label>
            <input id="billLName" name="BillingLastName" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="billStreet">Street Address</label>
            <input id="billStreet" name="BillingStreet" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="billCity">City</label>
            <input id="billCity" name="BillingCity" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="billState">State</label>
            <select id="billState" name="BillingState" required="required">
               <option value="AL">AL</option>
               <option value="AK">AK</option>
               <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
               <option value="AR">AR</option>
               <option value="CA">CA</option>
               <option value="CO">CO</option>
               <option value="CT">CT</option>
               <option value="DE">DE</option>
               <option value="DC">DC</option>
               <option value="FL">FL</option>
               <option value="GA">GA</option>
               <option value="HI">HI</option>
               <option value="ID">ID</option>
               <option value="IL">IL</option>
               <option value="IN">IN</option>
               <option value="IA">IA</option>
               <option value="KS">KS</option>
               <option value="KY">KY</option>
               <option value="LA">LA</option>
               <option value="ME">ME</option>
               <option value="MD">MD</option>
               <option value="MA">MA</option>
               <option value="MI">MI</option>
               <option value="MN">MN</option>
               <option value="MS">MS</option>
               <option value="MO">MO</option>
               <option value="MT">MT</option>
               <option value="NE">NE</option>
               <option value="NV">NV</option>
               <option value="NH">NH</option>
               <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
               <option value="NM">NM</option>
               <option value="NY">NY</option>
               <option value="NC">NC</option>
               <option value="ND">ND</option>
               <option value="OH">OH</option>
               <option value="OK">OK</option>
               <option value="OR">OR</option>
               <option value="PA">PA</option>
               <option value="RI">RI</option>
               <option value="SC">SC</option>
               <option value="SD">SD</option>
               <option value="TN">TN</option>
               <option value="TX">TX</option>
               <option value="UT">UT</option>
               <option value="VT">VT</option>
               <option value="VA">VA</option>
               <option value="WA">WA</option>
               <option value="WV">WV</option>
               <option value="WI">WI</option>
               <option value="WY">WY</option>
            </select>
            <label for="billZip">Zip</label>
            <input id="billZip" name="BillingZip" type="number" required="required" />
            <label for="billPhone">Phone</label>
            <input id="billPhone" name="BillingPhone" type="number" required="required" />
            <div class="errorMessage"></div>
         </fieldset>
         <fieldset id="deliveryAddress" class="text">
            <legend>Delivery Address</legend>
            <div class="checks">
               <input id="sameAddr" name="SameAddress" type="checkbox" />
               <label for="sameAddr">same as billing address</label>
            </div>
            <label for="delivFName">First Name</label>
            <input id="delivFName" name="DeliveryFirstName" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="delivLName">Last Name</label>
            <input id="delivLName" name="DeliveryLastName" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="delivStreet">Street Address</label>
            <input id="delivStreet" name="DeliveryStreet" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="delivCity">City</label>
            <input id="delivCity" name="DeliveryCity" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="delivState">State</label>
            <select id="delivState" name="DeliveryState" required="required">
               <option value="AL">AL</option>
               <option value="AK">AK</option>
               <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
               <option value="AR">AR</option>
               <option value="CA">CA</option>
               <option value="CO">CO</option>
               <option value="CT">CT</option>
               <option value="DE">DE</option>
               <option value="DC">DC</option>
               <option value="FL">FL</option>
               <option value="GA">GA</option>
               <option value="HI">HI</option>
               <option value="ID">ID</option>
               <option value="IL">IL</option>
               <option value="IN">IN</option>
               <option value="IA">IA</option>
               <option value="KS">KS</option>
               <option value="KY">KY</option>
               <option value="LA">LA</option>
               <option value="ME">ME</option>
               <option value="MD">MD</option>
               <option value="MA">MA</option>
               <option value="MI">MI</option>
               <option value="MN">MN</option>
               <option value="MS">MS</option>
               <option value="MO">MO</option>
               <option value="MT">MT</option>
               <option value="NE">NE</option>
               <option value="NV">NV</option>
               <option value="NH">NH</option>
               <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
               <option value="NM">NM</option>
               <option value="NY">NY</option>
               <option value="NC">NC</option>
               <option value="ND">ND</option>
               <option value="OH">OH</option>
               <option value="OK">OK</option>
               <option value="OR">OR</option>
               <option value="PA">PA</option>
               <option value="RI">RI</option>
               <option value="SC">SC</option>
               <option value="SD">SD</option>
               <option value="TN">TN</option>
               <option value="TX">TX</option>
               <option value="UT">UT</option>
               <option value="VT">VT</option>
               <option value="VA">VA</option>
               <option value="WA">WA</option>
               <option value="WV">WV</option>
               <option value="WI">WI</option>
               <option value="WY">WY</option>
            </select>
            <label for="delivZip">Zip</label>
            <input id="delivZip" name="DeliveryZip" type="number" required="required" />
            <label for="delivPhone">Phone</label>
            <input id="delivPhone" name="DeliveryPhone" type="number" required="required" />
            <div class="errorMessage"></div>
         </fieldset>
         <fieldset id="deliveryDate" class="checks">
            <legend>Delivery Date</legend>
            <div class="inline" id="delivDate">
               <select id="delivMo" name="DelivMonth" required="required">
                  <option value="1">January</option>
                  <option value="2">February</option>
                  <option value="3">March</option>
                  <option value="4">April</option>
                  <option value="5">May</option>
                  <option value="6">June</option>
                  <option value="7">July</option>
                  <option value="8">August</option>
                  <option value="9">September</option>
                  <option value="10">October</option>
                  <option value="11">November</option>
                  <option value="12">December</option>
               </select>
               <select id="delivDy" name="DelivDay" required="required">
                  <option value="1">1</option>
                  <option value="2">2</option>
                  <option value="3">3</option>
                  <option value="4">4</option>
                  <option value="5">5</option>
                  <option value="6">6</option>
                  <option value="7">7</option>
                  <option value="8">8</option>
                  <option value="9">9</option>
                  <option value="10">10</option>
                  <option value="11">11</option>
                  <option value="12">12</option>
                  <option value="13">13</option>
                  <option value="14">14</option>
                  <option value="15">15</option>
                  <option value="16">16</option>
                  <option value="17">17</option>
                  <option value="18">18</option>
                  <option value="19">19</option>
                  <option value="20">20</option>
                  <option value="21">21</option>
                  <option value="22">22</option>
                  <option value="23">23</option>
                  <option value="24">24</option>
                  <option value="25">25</option>
                  <option value="26">26</option>
                  <option value="27">27</option>
                  <option value="28">28</option>
                  <option value="29">29</option>
                  <option value="30">30</option>
                  <option value="31">31</option>
               </select>
               <select id="delivYr" name="DelivYear" required="required">
                  <option value="2017">2017</option>
                  <option value="2018">2018</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div class="errorMessage"></div>
         </fieldset>
         <fieldset id="paymentInfo" class="text">
            <legend>Payment</legend>
            <div id="cards" class="inline">
               <input id="visa" name="PaymentType" type="radio" value="Visa" />
               <label for="visa">Visa</label>
               <input id="mc" name="PaymentType" type="radio" value="MC" />
               <label for="mc">Master Card</label>
               <input id="discover" name="PaymentType" type="radio" value="Discover" />
               <label for="discover">Discover</label>
               <input id="amex" name="PaymentType" type="radio" value="AmEx" />
               <label for="amex">American Express</label>
            </div>
            <div>
               <label for="ccNum">Card #</label>
               <input id="ccNum" name="CardNumber" type="number" required="required" />
               <div id="ccNumErrorMessage"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
               <label>Expiration</label>
               <div class="inline" id="exp">
                  <label for="expMo" id="expMoLabel">Expiration Month</label>
                  <select id="expMo" name="ExpMonth" required="required">
                     <option value="01">01</option>
                     <option value="02">02</option>
                     <option value="03">03</option>
                     <option value="04">04</option>
                     <option value="05">05</option>
                     <option value="06">06</option>
                     <option value="07">07</option>
                     <option value="08">08</option>
                     <option value="09">09</option>
                     <option value="10">10</option>
                     <option value="11">11</option>
                     <option value="12">12</option>
                  </select>
                  <label for="expYr" id="expYrLabel">Expiration Year</label>
                  <select id="expYr" name="ExpYear" required="required">
                     <option value="2017">2017</option>
                     <option value="2018">2018</option>
                     <option value="2019">2019</option>
                     <option value="2020">2020</option>
                     <option value="2021">2021</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
               <input id="cvv" name="CVVValue" type="number" required="required" /> 
               <div id="cvvErrorMessage"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="errorMessage"></div>
         </fieldset>
         <fieldset id="createAccount" class="text">
            <legend>Create Account?</legend>
            <p>To be able to access your purchase history and make changes to your order, enter a name and password to create an account.</p>
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input id="username" name="NewUsername" type="text" />
            <label for="pass1">Password</label>
            <input id="pass1" name="Password1" type="password" />
            <label for="pass2">Password (verify)</label>
            <input id="pass2" name="Password2" type="password" />
            <div class="errorMessage"></div>
         </fieldset>
         <div id="buttonContainer">
            <input type="submit" value="Place Order" id="orderButton" />
         </div>
      </form>
   </article>
   <footer>Snoot Flowers <span>&bull;</span> Davenport, Iowa</footer>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript code.
What it is supposed to do it that when i check the check box "same as billing address" it is supposed to copy the information from the biling address form and fill up the shipping address form.

```
function copyBillingAddress() {
    var billingInputElements = document.querySelectorAll("#billingAddress input");
    var deliveryInputElements = document.querySelectorAll("#deliveryAddress input");
    if (document.getElementById("sameAddr").checked) {
    for (var i = 0; i < billingInputElements.length; i++) {
    deliveryInputElements[i + 1].value = billingInputElements[i].value;
} 
    document.querySelector("#deliveryAddress select").value = document.querySelector("#billingAddress select").value;
}else {
    for (var i = 0; i < billingInputElements.length; i++) {
    deliveryInputElements[i + 1].value = "";
    }
    document.querySelector("#deliveryAddress select").selectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
function createEventListener() {
    var same = document.getElementById("sameAddr");
    if (same.addEventListener) {
        same.addEventListener("click", copyBillingAddress, false);
    } else if (same.attachEvent) {
            same.attachEvent("onclick", copyBillingAddress);
    }
}
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not a problem to be solved.  What's actually going wrong?

Comment: Well it is supposed to copy the information from the billing address to the shipping address but when i check the box nothing happens.

Comment: Can you remove the trailing "}" after document.querySelector("#deliveryAddress select").selectedIndex = -1;

Comment: That closes the function

Comment: It would be really useful if you added some HTML to back this up so we can actually test it and see the problem live rather than having to try imagine the rest of the code and debug

Comment: I updated it to show the html

Comment: I've provided the solution. Please not that I've removed all unnecessary html and only left what is required for the question.

Comment: One of the things you didn't do is that you didn't call your function createEventListener()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call your `createEventListener()`. You can just simplify it this way(unless you are obviously targeting older browsers):

```js
(function(){

  function copyBillingAddress() 
  {
      var billingInputElements = document.querySelectorAll("#billingAddress input");
      var deliveryInputElements = document.querySelectorAll("#deliveryAddress input");
      if (document.getElementById("sameAddr").checked) 
      {
        for (var i = 0; i < billingInputElements.length; i++) 
        {
          deliveryInputElements[i + 1].value = billingInputElements[i].value;
        } 
        document.querySelector("#deliveryAddress select").value = document.querySelector("#billingAddress select").value;
      }else 
      {
        for (var i = 0; i < billingInputElements.length; i++) 
        {
          deliveryInputElements[i + 1].value = "";
        }
        document.querySelector("#deliveryAddress select").selectedIndex = -1;
      }
  }

  document.getElementById("sameAddr").addEventListener('change', 
    function()
    {
      copyBillingAddress();
    }
  );
})();
```

```html
<form action="results.htm">
         <fieldset id="billingAddress" class="text">
            <legend>Billing Address</legend>
            <label for="billFName">First Name</label>
            <input id="billFName" name="BillingFirstName" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="billLName">Last Name</label>
            <input id="billLName" name="BillingLastName" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="billStreet">Street Address</label>
            <input id="billStreet" name="BillingStreet" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="billCity">City</label>
            <input id="billCity" name="BillingCity" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="billState">State</label>
            <select id="billState" name="BillingState" required="required">
               <option value="AL">AL</option>
               <option value="AK">AK</option>
               <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
               <option value="AR">AR</option>
               <option value="CA">CA</option>
               <option value="CO">CO</option>
               <option value="CT">CT</option>
               <option value="DE">DE</option>
               <option value="DC">DC</option>
               <option value="FL">FL</option>
               <option value="GA">GA</option>
               <option value="HI">HI</option>
               <option value="ID">ID</option>
               <option value="IL">IL</option>
               <option value="IN">IN</option>
               <option value="IA">IA</option>
               <option value="KS">KS</option>
               <option value="KY">KY</option>
               <option value="LA">LA</option>
               <option value="ME">ME</option>
               <option value="MD">MD</option>
               <option value="MA">MA</option>
               <option value="MI">MI</option>
               <option value="MN">MN</option>
               <option value="MS">MS</option>
               <option value="MO">MO</option>
               <option value="MT">MT</option>
               <option value="NE">NE</option>
               <option value="NV">NV</option>
               <option value="NH">NH</option>
               <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
               <option value="NM">NM</option>
               <option value="NY">NY</option>
               <option value="NC">NC</option>
               <option value="ND">ND</option>
               <option value="OH">OH</option>
               <option value="OK">OK</option>
               <option value="OR">OR</option>
               <option value="PA">PA</option>
               <option value="RI">RI</option>
               <option value="SC">SC</option>
               <option value="SD">SD</option>
               <option value="TN">TN</option>
               <option value="TX">TX</option>
               <option value="UT">UT</option>
               <option value="VT">VT</option>
               <option value="VA">VA</option>
               <option value="WA">WA</option>
               <option value="WV">WV</option>
               <option value="WI">WI</option>
               <option value="WY">WY</option>
            </select>
            <label for="billZip">Zip</label>
            <input id="billZip" name="BillingZip" type="number" required="required" />
            <label for="billPhone">Phone</label>
            <input id="billPhone" name="BillingPhone" type="number" required="required" />
            <div class="errorMessage"></div>
         </fieldset>
         <fieldset id="deliveryAddress" class="text">
            <legend>Delivery Address</legend>
            <div class="checks">
               <input id="sameAddr" name="SameAddress" type="checkbox" />
               <label for="sameAddr">same as billing address</label>
            </div>
            <label for="delivFName">First Name</label>
            <input id="delivFName" name="DeliveryFirstName" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="delivLName">Last Name</label>
            <input id="delivLName" name="DeliveryLastName" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="delivStreet">Street Address</label>
            <input id="delivStreet" name="DeliveryStreet" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="delivCity">City</label>
            <input id="delivCity" name="DeliveryCity" type="text" required="required" />
            <label for="delivState">State</label>
            <select id="delivState" name="DeliveryState" required="required">
               <option value="AL">AL</option>
               <option value="AK">AK</option>
               <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
               <option value="AR">AR</option>
               <option value="CA">CA</option>
               <option value="CO">CO</option>
               <option value="CT">CT</option>
               <option value="DE">DE</option>
               <option value="DC">DC</option>
               <option value="FL">FL</option>
               <option value="GA">GA</option>
               <option value="HI">HI</option>
               <option value="ID">ID</option>
               <option value="IL">IL</option>
               <option value="IN">IN</option>
               <option value="IA">IA</option>
               <option value="KS">KS</option>
               <option value="KY">KY</option>
               <option value="LA">LA</option>
               <option value="ME">ME</option>
               <option value="MD">MD</option>
               <option value="MA">MA</option>
               <option value="MI">MI</option>
               <option value="MN">MN</option>
               <option value="MS">MS</option>
               <option value="MO">MO</option>
               <option value="MT">MT</option>
               <option value="NE">NE</option>
               <option value="NV">NV</option>
               <option value="NH">NH</option>
               <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
               <option value="NM">NM</option>
               <option value="NY">NY</option>
               <option value="NC">NC</option>
               <option value="ND">ND</option>
               <option value="OH">OH</option>
               <option value="OK">OK</option>
               <option value="OR">OR</option>
               <option value="PA">PA</option>
               <option value="RI">RI</option>
               <option value="SC">SC</option>
               <option value="SD">SD</option>
               <option value="TN">TN</option>
               <option value="TX">TX</option>
               <option value="UT">UT</option>
               <option value="VT">VT</option>
               <option value="VA">VA</option>
               <option value="WA">WA</option>
               <option value="WV">WV</option>
               <option value="WI">WI</option>
               <option value="WY">WY</option>
            </select>
            <label for="delivZip">Zip</label>
            <input id="delivZip" name="DeliveryZip" type="number" required="required" />
            <label for="delivPhone">Phone</label>
            <input id="delivPhone" name="DeliveryPhone" type="number" required="required" />
            <div class="errorMessage"></div>
         </fieldset>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function copyAddress() {
  const textValues = ['attention', 'line_one', 'line_two', 'zip_code'];
  
  textValues.forEach(function (item, index) {
      document.getElementById(`billingaddress-${item}`).value = document.getElementById(`mailingaddress-${item}`).value;
  });
}
```